# Does applying dc bias to a signal make it stronger?

Tags: amplifier, dc, biasing

I worked on a device that mimics a triode vacuum tube. But it doesn't use any vacuum, instead, it uses an electrolyte. I got several of them working, and I can make them switch, by making the "grid" positive.

You'll see, it has two wires, and a serpentine-shaped one, that's my grid. If a current runs between the two plain wires, another running between one of them and the grid (that is placed in the middle) can control the other. Just like in a normal triode vacuum tube.

I've reached current gain.

But I want it to amplify analog signals, rather than only switching digitally. So I hooked up everthing as it shows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3FqxJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The microphone and the battery attached to it are an Audio source.

By making the grid positive, I noticed that the signal sounds a bit louder. 
But I think I'm applying DC bias. Because I put a LED in series with the speaker and it shined all the time, but still followed the signal.

And if you simplify the circuit, I'm just putting the battery in series.

So, First: Am I applying DC bias? and Second: Does the DC bias make the signal louder?

Anyway, I hope this is understandable. Thanks by now.

Comment: It is unclear how your device actually works, as it is that schematic does not make much sense to me. Anyway, if it was a proper triode based or transistor based circuit then the DC bias by itself does not make the signal louder. Fact is that such amplifiers need a DC bias, a **higher** DC bias usually also means that the **gain** becomes **higher** meaning that the same input signal would generate a higher output signal.

Comment: the MIC should be controlling the grid, not the output

Comment: Interesting! I've made magnetic amplifiers, but haven't heard of an electrolytic one. Could you provide a reference or picture? Though I understand how it might work, using ionic flow rather than free electrons, would its frequency response be high enough for audio?

Comment: There’s much to be gained by impedance matching here. But a single stage won’t do much power.